# I send an email with html from my method with java mail and only in gmail it arrives broken and without some styles, what is it?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, gmail, jakarta-mail

this is my main method and the second one is where I call it. The way that my html format seems to be right, styles are inline and this works when I send it to an outlook user or when I put the html manually in gmail inside of the following div:

```html
<div id=":vn" class="Am Al editable LW-avf tS-tW" hidefocus="true" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr; min-height: 266px;" spellcheck="false" aria-owns=":y1" aria-controls=":y1" aria-expanded="false"></div>
```

main method:

```
public void enviarEmail(String destinatario, String asunto, String contenidoHtml, String contentType) throws MessagingException {
    // Configuración de las propiedades
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.hostinger.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

    // Crear una nueva sesión con autenticación
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    // Crear el mensaje
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(destinatario));
    message.setSubject(asunto);
    // Especificar UTF-8 en el contenido
    message.setContent(contenidoHtml, contentType);

    // Enviar el mensaje
    Transport.send(message);
}
```

and then I call it in this method:

```
public void enviarTicketsPorEmail(String correoDestinatario, Carrito carrito) throws MessagingException {
    StringBuilder cuerpoEmail = new StringBuilder();

    // .newsletter-recibo-de-tickets
    cuerpoEmail.append("<!DOCTYPE html>")
            .append("<html>")
            .append("<head>")
            .append("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">")
            .append("<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"text/html; IE=edge\">")
            .append("<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">")
            .append("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;900&display=swap\" />")
            .append("</head>")

            //body
            .append("<div style=\"margin:0;line-height:normal; display:flex; flex-direction: column; width:100%;justify-content: center;align-items: center;align-content: center;flex-wrap: nowrap;\">")

            .append("<div style=\"width: 100%;\">")
            .append("<img src=\"https://simplepassbucket.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/img/newsletters/parteInicialCompraExitosa.png\" style=\"width: 100%;\">")
            .append("</div>")
            .append("<div style=\"line-height:130%;display:inline-block;font-size:14px;margin:10px 0\">")
                    .append("<span style:'font-size: 14px'>Código de compra: <span style=\"font-weight:600; font-size: 14px\" id=\"m_-4881203300558445123codigoCompra\">")
            .append(carrito.getPago().getPagoId())
            .append("</span>")
            .append("</span>")
            .append("</div>")

       
//THE REST OF THE CODE WAS REMOVED SO IT IS NOT SO LONG


            .append("</div>")
            .append("</html>");
    // Usar la función de envío de correo para enviar el correo con el cuerpo construido y el tipo de contenido correcto
    mailSender.enviarEmail(correoDestinatario, "Tus tickets :)", cuerpoEmail.toString(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
}
```

I have already explained it up there but yeaph basically I need an example of a method in java mail that has been able to send an html automatically to a gmail user without it breaking or arriving deformed.

Comment: Most email clients do not load external stylesheets. In fact, a lot of email client will generally require quite some styling on the HTML elements itself, and even ignore inline stylesheets. Creating usable HTML emails is a craft in itself, and you can't use all tricks used for "normal" HTML pages.

Comment: When sending HTML emails everything has to be inlined, so if you want to use a custom stylesheet it has to be part of the HTML that is being send, not some remote resource that is going to be loaded (images are a general exception to the rule_. So I doubt your fonts are getting loaded which probably is why it is (partially) misformed.

Answer (score 0):

I was using display: flex; which is not supported by gmail. I solved it by implementing table structure.